# Hello how can i joint table in progress 4gl? And display

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

Define variable i as integer no-undo.

```
For each Sports.customer where Sports.customer.CustNum = 1 AND Sports.Order.OrderDate = 11/21/1997 NO-LOCK. 
/* it says Missing for find etc */
```

I need to display the Order of Lift Tours i used his primary key but im having trouble to access the 2 tables

Tables
 Customer PK CustNum
 Order  PK OrderName FK CustNum

```
     Order-line PK Orderline
```

I need to display the Orders of Lift Tours with the date order of 11/21/1997 and diplay total price of lift tours

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

```
define variable orderTotal as decimal no-undo.

for each customer no-lock where name = "Lift Tours",
    each order no-lock where order.custNum = customer.custNum and order.orderDate = 11/21/1997,
    each orderLine no-lock where orderLine.orderNum = order.orderNum:

  orderTotal = orderTotal + ( orderLine.Qty * orderLine.price ).

end.

display orderTotal.
```

The "," is used to join WHERE clauses in the FOR EACH.  You specify the common fields to make the join on in those WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 2):

For total price, you'll have to join Order and OrderLine.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE deTotal AS DECIMAL NO-UNDO. 
FOR EACH Order WHERE Order.CustNum = 1 AND Order.OrderDate = 11/21/1997 NO-LOCK, 
    EACH OrderLine OF Order NO-LOCK:
    ASSIGN deTotal = deTotal = deTotal + OrderLine.Qty * OrderLine.Price . 
END.
```

Comment: Mike, you’ve got a couple of typos in that snippet.  WHERE rather than AND as well as an OR that you probably intended to be an OF (and I discourage use of OF, it obfuscates the fields used to make the join).